# IllegalAccessError and proxy

Tags: java, clojure

I'm translating [this code](http://doc.trolltech.com/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-pathstroke-code.html) to Clojure. As you can see, I have to extend the class `ArthurFrame`, yet I'm getting an `IllegalAccessError` everytime I use `(proxy [ArthurFrame] [] ...)`.

Any idea why? Here is the [class's source](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-jambi/qt-jambi/blobs/2131440f843e1a6d259d0fe3f2a3ed58157ef118/com/trolltech/demos/ArthurFrame.java).

Thanks!

**EDIT:** [Here is the full error stack](http://pastebin.com/0Zna0MTq) for running (proxy [ArthurFrame] []) on the REPL.

**EDIT 2**: Actually it seems that even instantiating the class yields an error. Here is the output from `(ArthurFrame. wid)`:

```
tried to access class com.trolltech.demos.ArthurFrame from class user$eval__2205
  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalAccessError]

Restarts:
 0: [ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.

Backtrace:
  0: user$eval__2205.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
  1: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:4642)
  2: clojure.core$eval__5254.invoke(core.clj:2031)
  3: swank.commands.basic$eval_region__907.invoke(basic.clj:40)
  4: swank.commands.basic$eval_region__907.invoke(basic.clj:31)
  5: swank.commands.basic$eval__927$listener_eval__929.invoke(basic.clj:54)
  6: clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:359)
  7: user$eval__2202.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE)
  8: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:4642)
  9: clojure.core$eval__5254.invoke(core.clj:2031)
 10: swank.core$eval_in_emacs_package__455.invoke(core.clj:59)
 11: swank.core$eval_for_emacs__533.invoke(core.clj:128)
 12: clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:367)
 13: clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:179)
 14: clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:476)
 15: clojure.core$apply__4379.invoke(core.clj:434)
 16: swank.core$eval_from_control__458.invoke(core.clj:66)
 17: swank.core$eval_loop__461.invoke(core.clj:71)
 18: swank.core$spawn_repl_thread__595$fn__627$fn__629.invoke(core.clj:183)
 19: clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:171)
 20: clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:164)
 21: clojure.core$apply__4379.invoke(core.clj:434)
 22: swank.core$spawn_repl_thread__595$fn__627.doInvoke(core.clj:180)
 23: clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:402)
 24: clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:37)
 25: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Can you, please, give full exception stack trace?

Comment: Could you please include code in the question instead of linking to code. Links break.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that ArthurFrame visibility is package not public so the proxy can't access it since the proxy doesn't belong to the package com.trolltech.demos. You have to make ArthurFrame public.

Comment: Living and learning... I thought the default behaviour was to set it public!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of your problem is that something has not been recompiled.  Here's the javadoc description of the `IllegalAccessError` exception:

> Thrown if an application attempts to access or modify a field, or to call a method that it does not have access to.
>
> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

To be more specific, this normally happens when you have classes `A` and `B`, where `B` depends on some members of `A`.  Then you do something like this:

1. You compile `A`, then `B`.
2. Make an incompatible change to `A` and recompile it *without* recompiling `B`.  In this case, the change would involve reducing the visibility of some member of `A` that `B` uses so that the member should no longer be visible to `B`.
3. Run an application that uses `A` and `B` and and you will get an `IllegalAccessError`.

**EDIT**

The proxy class that is trying to do the accessing looks like it must have been generated by the Clojure compiler.  So maybe there is a Clojure compiler bug ... or maybe you changed the visibility of `ArthurFrame` after you ran the Clojure compiler.  Either way, one possible fix is to change the visibility of the `ArthurFrame` to `public`.